# "ツール" meaning "nerd"/"obscure"? What is being said here?

Tags: words, slang, spoken-language, listening

In a recent video by The Anime Man (Joey), he talks with a host (ROLAND), and they get to talking about anime, and how it's less stigmatized and more mainstream now.
Then Joey brings up the point that there's a culture of "the more obscure the anime you watch, that's considered cooler". They keep referring to "obscure" as something that sounds like "ツール", but I can't find anything relevant about that. Can someone tell me what word they're using here, and what it means?

The video: https://youtu.be/5LSva1m4Ytw?t=1508

One place they use it is starting from 25:08

What their dialogue sounds like to me:

Joey: "もうワンピース以外っていうか、その人気以外のアニメを見るほうがカッコいいみたいな変な文化が出てきたんですよね。"

ROLAND: "ああ、ツール(?)だみたいな"

Joey: "そう、ツール(?)な文化が出てきたんですよね。"

Another place they use it is at is 30:16 ( https://youtu.be/5LSva1m4Ytw?t=1816 )

What the dialogue sounds like to me:

ROLAND: "*brings up Odd Taxi*"

Joey: "*laughs* めっちゃツール(?)じゃないっすか？" (Translated as: "Yeah. That's super obscure.")

Anyways, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word he used is **通 (つう)**. There is no ル.

Related: [What are the nuances in various words for "expert"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96485/5010)

Comment: Thanks! If I can ask as a quick follow-up, can 通 (in this context) have the connotation of elitism/snobbery?

Comment: @chausies Yes it does have such a connotation (similar to 玄人) in this particular context. (BTW I do hear ル at 25:14, but I believe this is just a mispronunciation)

Comment: @chausies Let me correct this a bit. This 通 refers to a "hardcore/elite anime fan", but not a "snobbish anime fan". They're obviously using the term in a positive manner.